# Optimizing a MySQL search query with MATCH() AGAINST()

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT `o`.`fruits_id` 
FROM `fruits` as `o` JOIN `fruits_categories` as `oc` ON `o`.`fruits_id` = `oc`.`fruits_id` 
JOIN `categories` as `c` ON `c`.`cat_id` = `oc`.`cat_id` 
JOIN `fruits_location` as `ol` ON `o`.`fruits_id` = `ol`.`fruits_id` 
JOIN `location` as `l` ON `l`.`location_id` = `ol`.`location_id` 
JOIN `fruits_price` as `op` ON `o`.`fruits_id` = `op`.`fruits_id` 
JOIN `price` as `p` ON `p`.`price_id` = `op`.`price_id` 
WHERE ( (MATCH (c.cat_name) AGAINST ('apple') OR MATCH (l.location_name) AGAINST ('apple') OR MATCH (o.fruits_name, o.fruits_description, o.address, o.instagram_tag) AGAINST ('apple') OR MATCH (p.price_name) AGAINST ('apple') ) 
AND (MATCH (c.cat_name) AGAINST ('orange') OR MATCH (l.location_name) AGAINST ('orange') MATCH (o.fruits_name, o.fruits_description, o.address, o.instagram_tag) AGAINST ('orange') OR OR MATCH (p.price_name) AGAINST ('orange') ) ) LIMIT 9
```

When I run this in phpmyadmin, it takes about 3 seconds to process, which I think is good.

But when I run this inside a PHP file (results paginated), it takes about 11 seconds to finished.

I'm guessing there is still a more optimized query that can achieve the result.

Thanks and I appreciate any help.

B

Comment: Are you sure that it is the query that runs for 12 secs and not sg else within the php code causes the issue?

Comment: not sure what 'sg' means in sg else

Comment: Sg=Something it's a common abbreviation

Comment: is there a way to test that?

Comment: Time the query separately. You can simplify your where criteria as well: do not search the same field separately for apple and orange, use just one search with apple orange.

Comment: I did a search for apple only then did a search for orange only and yeah it loaded the same time when I had both on the search

Comment: 11 seconds when searching for only 1 fruit. the same when searching more 2 fruits